# How to remove divergent values from a list

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm extracting some data from some images to get a graph but some of the values extracted are wrong (the diverging values), is there I way to remove them without changing the length of the list. I tried to calculate the mean and assign it to those values but apparently, the mean is so big too.

[image]

Comment: Set them to np.nan or use np.mask...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `data` is a `np.array` :

```
min_value = 12 # The minimal value of your data, below it the points will be considered to be diverging. Change it as you want.
good_data = data[data > min_value] # Using advanced indexing
good_mean = np.mean(good_data)

new_data = np.where(data > min_value, data, good_mean)
```

Comment: the problem is that there is no 'min_value' in my data. The sudden change in the value without keeping the same value is what determines if it's wrong or not.

Comment: In that case the problem is much more complicated since it's really hard to define precisely what is a divergent value, as by definition your `data` points are supposed to change. I'd recommand you check different statistical methods to smooth your curb, such as [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), [Exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing)...